# How to put condition for the task in a react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]I would like to add an important condition in a checkbox form. When a user adds some task and check on the small checkbox (which is an indication of important task!) should be displayed bold in the application. May I ask please how to define such conditions?

```
function Form(props){
    const [name, setName ] = useState('');
    const [important, setImportant] = useState(false);
    
    function handleChangeImportant(e){
        console.log(e);
        e.preventDefault();
        setImportant(e.target.checked);
        if(important ){
            alert('this task is important');
            setName("");
        }
    };
    
    function handleChange(e) {
        setName(e.target.value);
    }

    function handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //alert('Moin');
        if(name == ''){
            alert('Please enter a valid task name');
        }
        
        if(name !== ''){
            props.addTask(name);
            setName("");
        }
    }    
    return(
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}> 
            <h2 className="label-wrapper">
                <label htmlFor="new-todo-input" className="label__lg">
                    What needs to be done?
                </label>
            </h2>
            
            <input 
                type="text"
                id="new-todo-input"
                className="input input__lg"
                name="text"
                autoComplete="off"
                value={name}
                onChange={handleChange}                
            />
            
            <input
                type="checkbox"
                id="todo-0" 
                value={important}
                onChange={handleChangeImportant}                             
            /> Important
            
            <button type = "submit" className="btn btn__primary btn__lg">
                Add
            </button>
        </form>
    );
}

export default Form;
```

***I render the taskList like follows***

In the application, The tasklist is rendered as following.

```
const taskList = tasks.filter(FILTER_MAP[filter]).map(task => (
    <ToDo 
      id ={task.id} 
      name={task.name} 
      completed={task.completed}
      key ={task.id}
      toggleTaskCompleted={toggleTaskCompleted}
      deleteTask={deleteTask}
      editTask={editTask}
      />
      )
  );
```

Comment: how do you render the tasks list?

Comment: @AadilMehraj, I updated the question and showed hoe I render the tasks list.

Comment: How about ```<Todo isImportant={isImportant} ... />``` and display bold if it's true?

Comment: @Watanabe.N, thank you for your help. May I ask you please to elaborate the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `Todo` component add another prop as `important`, based on that set the style/class of task heading bold.

```
<ToDo 
      ...
      important={task.important}
      ...
      />
```

Then within your component where you show task name:

```
<p style={{ fontWeight: props.important ? 'bold' : 'normal' }}>{props.name}</p>
```